# unable to get href Attributes using JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Below is my PHP code. I am displaying 3 images, if I Click over any image or product I need to add that product in the popup modal. I am trying to get the product name but I can't. How to solve this issue.

```
<?php
    $i   = 0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo"<td style='background-color:#FFFFFF;' height='383'>
               <a href='#myModal?productname={$row["productname"]} 'id='burl' role='button' data-productname='{$row["productname"]}' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>
                   <img src='images/{$row["productname"]}.jpg' width='255'/>
               </a>
             </td>";
    }
    mysql_free_result($result);
 ?>
```

JQuery Codings:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        console.log($(this).data('productname'));
    })
})
```

Comment: Normally just $(selector).attr('href');

Comment: Kindly use *mysqli_fetch_assos* instead of *mysql_fetch_assoc* as it has been deprecated

Comment: `$(this).attr('data-productname')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function ()
 {
            $('#myPopup').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) 
{
                var rowid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('productname');
                alert(rowid);
                $.ajax(
{
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'fetch_data.php', //Here you will fetch records
                    data: 'productname=' + rowid, //Pass $id
                    success: function (data)
 {
                        $('.fetched-data').html(data);//Show fetched data from database                      
                    }
                });
            });
        });

This coding solved my problem.
Thanks for all your reply.
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` inside modal event is not your clicked element instance, but the modal itself. You should use `relatedTarget` like so :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
                                             // ^--- Add here
      var 
        relatedData = $( e.relatedTarget ),
        productname = relatedData.data( 'productname' );

      console.log( productname );
   })
})
```